# Transposing rows that have a common row value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a table that has three columns and I want to transpose the score and time_step columns into rows for each unique stay_id. so what is the easiest way of doing it using Pandas python library?

[This is the original table:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tT1uv.png)
[Thew desired output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BdjC.png)

Answer (score 1):

> you have to use 'df.pivot'.

```
new_df= df.pivot(index='stay_id', columns='time_step',values='score')
print(new_df)
```